# Append values from 2 different columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, append

I have the following table

[image]

I need to get the following output as "SVGFRAMXPOSLSVG" from the 2 columns.
Is it possible to get this appended values from 2 columns

Comment: I am using the Oracle DBMS

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT  '' +   DEPART_AIRPORT_CODE + ARRIVE_AIRPORT_CODE
            FROM @tblName
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 0, '')
```

Comment: Its not working, getting some right parenthesis missing error .

Answer (score 0):

For Example:-

```
Declare @tbl Table(
id INT ,
DEPART_AIRPORT_CODE   Varchar(50),
ARRIVE_AIRPORT_CODE  Varchar(50),

value varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'g1','g2',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(2,'g2','g3',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(3,'g3','g1',NULL)

SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT  '' +   DEPART_AIRPORT_CODE + ARRIVE_AIRPORT_CODE
            FROM @tbl
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 0, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

Use [Analytic functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) and `listagg` to get the job done.

**Detail**

Create two lists of `code_id` and `code` values. Match the `code_id` values for the same airport codes (passengers depart from the same airport they just arrived at). Using `lag` and `lead` to grab values from other rows. `NULL`s will exist for `code_id` at the start and end of the itinerary. Default the first `NULL` to `0`, and the last `NULL` to be the previous `code_id` plus 1. A list of codes will be produced, with a matching index. Merge the lists together and remove duplicates by using a `union`. Finally use `listagg` with no delimiter to aggregate the rows onto a string value.

```
with codes as
(
    select
    nvl(lag(t1.id) over (order by t1.id),0) as code_id,
    t1.depart_airport_code as code
    from table1 t1

    union

    select
    nvl(lead(t1.id) over (order by t1.id)-1,lag(t1.id) over (order by t1.id)+1) as code_id,
    t1.arrive_airport_code as code
    from table1 t1
)
select
listagg(c.code,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.code_id) as result
from codes c;
```

**Note:** This solution does rely on an integer `id` field being available. Otherwise the analytic functions wouldn't have a column to sort by. If `id` doesn't exist, then you would need to manufacture one based on another column, such as a timestamp or another identifier that ensures the rows are in the correct order.
Use `row_number() over (order by myorderedidentifier) as id` in a subquery or view to achieve this. *Don't* use `rownum`. It could give you unpredictable results. Without an `ORDER BY` clause, there is no guarantee that the same query will return the same results each time.

**Output**

```
|          RESULT |
|-----------------|
| SVGFRAMXPOSLSVG |
```